# NullPointerException on rootview of an included Layout

Tags: android

Good day, i am getting a NullPointerexception when trying to access a RelativeLayout  viewgroup of an included layout.  In the code below it is named rootlayout.
i have this

date_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@+id/my_layoutroot_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_from1_id"
                style="@style/date_text"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/date_from1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_from2_id"
                style="@style/date_text"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/date_from1_id"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/date_from1_id"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/date_To1" />
               <TextView
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and in the main_layout.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/date_layout" android:id="@+id/datelayout_id"></include>"


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my code is:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        View view = findViewById(R.id.datelayout_id);
          rootlayout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.my_layoutroot_id);
          rootlayout.setOnclickListener(this);   // am getting the NullPointerException here
```

any idea what i could be doing wrong? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are assigning a new id in main_layout.xml:

```
    <include layout="@layout/date_layout" android:id="@+id/datelayout_id">
```

`rootlayout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.datelayout_id);` should fix the NPE.

Comment: thanks. But why is this?, is it because its the root layout thats why its done like this? what i mean is, if i want to access the TextViews, i use their assigned id and it works.

Comment: You are not assigning new IDs to TextViews that's why.

Answer (score 4):

Either remove layout id from main layout or from date layout.

Just replace

```
<include layout="@layout/date_layout" android:id="@+id/datelayout_id"></include>"
```

with

```
<include layout="@layout/date_layout"></include>"
```

Comment: this is great answer! Thank you very much!